# WinSCP hangs after uploading files to SFTP

Tags: ssis, winscp, sql-server-agent

I have a SSIS package. Package has an Execute Process Task. Execute Process Task has a Executable property set as
**C:\Program  Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe** and Argument property set as below:

```
/console /command "open sftp://UserName:Password@sftpserverpath.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 1234 1x:2x:3x:4x:5x:6x:12:1x:21:60:81:e6:a2:3e:b3:c6""" "put \\ServeName\Share\Reporting\Weekly\*.txt /Reports/"  /log="\\ServerName\Share\Reporting\Weekly\WinSCPLogs\winscp1.log" /loglevel=2 "exit"
```

I am running this package from SQL Server Agent Job. When I run the job it uploads the files then continue running for indefinite time. WinSCP log is attached [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1szQD32KcgoRiuccTkejkjjvDasSInlzz/view?usp=drivesdk).

Comment: You log is not publicly accessible. And you need to include the log directly into your question anyway.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Please try again.

Comment: What time did you collect the logs? It looks like you did collect them in the middle of the upload.

Comment: Are you aware that with `/loglevel=2`, the upload will take magnitudes longer?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It was only 3 files I was trying to upload. And even after uploading 3 files it was keep running so I stopped the job. If you can check the logs at the end it says,
. 2020-07-22 20:23:59.124 Copying finished: Transferred: 2,112,574, Elapsed: 0:00:27, CPS: 80,079/s
. 2020-07-22 20:23:59.124 Session upkeep
. 2020-07-22 20:23:59.124 Looking for network events
. 2020-07-22 20:23:59.124 Timeout waiting for network events

Comment: So what time did you collect the logs? Did you check that the WinSCP process is still running? Or was it killed somehow?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I removed log from the command and worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I removed log from the command and worked.

```
/console /command "open sftp://UserName:Password@sftpserverpath.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 1234 1x:2x:3x:4x:5x:6x:12:1x:21:60:81:e6:a2:3e:b3:c6""" "put \\ServeName\Share\Reporting\Weekly\*.txt /Reports/" "exit"
```